# Heading 3 font size appearing slightly larger than Heading 1 and 2 of same size

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2016, styles, custom-multilevel-lists

Word 2016. Have lengthy experience (fighting) with multi-level lists. Recently Heading 3 is appearing slightly larger and bolder in the text and Table of Contents though the multi-level list settings and style Heading 3 attributes are same font size as Heading 1 and Heading 2. Only difference is Heading 1 is All Caps, Heading 2 is Small Caps, and Heading 3 is only Bold. Heading 4 is regular italic. I have created multi-level list outlines and style sheets in a new/blank document over and over, saved as a template, and to use, paste in unformatted text, and then apply styles to each component and it's still happening. Even had IT uninstall and reinstall Word. I've dealt with the black box for heading numbers occasionally for 7 years now, and recently experienced it again. None of the standard fixes worked, so I have to create that document from scratch again.

Most of the documents I work on are based on documents my coworkers pick up from prior projects and revised for the new projects. Several people may work on them. Again, even if I start from a blank document and copy and paste over plain text and then apply my newly-created style sheet to each heading/paragraph/caption, etc., this is happening. It used to be worse, with noticeably larger and slightly blurry Heading 3 or other heading level numbers and/or text. Multi-level lists have always been a nightmare.

Also for the first time, Word is bogging down for landscape pages within a portrait document. Any ideas? I'm desperate! I've wasted so much time trying to fix this/these issues. It makes my job hell! Thank you in advance for any suggestions!